# Simple PHP statement, I can't get it to work!

Tags: php

How to get $schedule = true` and $schedule2 = true to work?

I know this is easy and I'm overlooking something simple!

Here is the full code:

I basically want schedule and schedule2 to work (it looks at a PHP date and tells it when to expire on our news site!)

```
$where = array();
$where = run_filters('also-allow', $where);

if ($allow_full_story or $allow_add_comment) {
    $post = 'full';

    if ($title){
        $where[] = "url = $title";
    } elseif ($time){
        $where[] = "date = $time";
    } elseif ($id){
        $where[] = "id = $id";
    }
} else {
    $post = 'short';

    if (!$is_logged_in or $is_logged_in and $member['level'] == 4) {
        $where[] = 'hidden = 0';
        $where[] = 'and';
    }

    if ($user or $author) {
        $where[] = 'author = '.($author ? $author : $user);
        $where[] = 'and';
    }

    if ($year and !$month) {
        $where[] = 'date > '.@mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year);
        $where[] = 'and';
        $where[] = 'date < '.@mktime(23, 59, 59, ($year == date("Y") ? date("n") : 12), ($year == date("Y") ? date("d") : 31), $year);
    } elseif ($year and $month and !$day) {
        $where[] = 'date > '.@mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
        $where[] = 'and';
        $where[] = 'date < '.@mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, (($year == date("Y") and $month >= date("n")) ? date("d") : 31), $year);
    } elseif ($year and $month and $day) {
        if($year == date("Y") and $month >= date("n") and $day >= date("d")) {
            $where[] = 'hidden = 2';
        }
        else {
            $where[] = 'date > '.@mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
            $where[] = 'and';
            $where[] = 'date < '.@mktime(23, 59, 59, $month, $day, $year);
        }
    }
    else {
    if ($schedule) {
        $where[] = 'date > '.(time() + $config_date_adjust * 60 - 432000);
    }
    else {
        $where[] = 'date < '.(time() + $config_date_adjust * 60);
    }
    $schedule = false;
}
else {
    if ($schedule2) {
        $where[] = 'date > '.(time() + $config_date_adjust * 60 - 86400);
    }
    else {
        $where[] = 'date < '.(time() + $config_date_adjust * 60);
    }
    $schedule2 = false;
}
```

Comment: What? Can you explain what you expect this code to do, and what it is actually doing instead?

Comment: @Tyler: Looks like he is building an sql statement

Comment: @SeanJA Yes, but I mean with regard to what he's trying to use `$schedule` for, and what effect he is unable to accomplish with it.

Comment: @OP What are you even referring to? There is no `$schedule = true` in your program...

Comment: @eberswine: I think the code that is before this fragment might be helpful to find the solution to the problem you are having.

Comment: I'm not a great PHP programmer or anything, but I must say, you need to comment your code more often, and perhaps beautify it a bit. This is attrocious

Comment: Thanks for posting more code context, but you still haven't explained what "working" would mean for this code. "X doesn't work" isn't an answerable question if you haven't said what X is supposed to be doing in the first place. (And preferably also said what it is doing instead)

Answer (score 7):

You can't have 2 `else`s in a row.
Maybe `elseif`, but no one know your logic.

Comment: He only has 1 `else` for each `if`. If you look closely, you will see. (Granted, the code formatting is atrocious)

Comment: Nah, it has else else in it: `else {...  $schedule = false;} else{ if(...` I checked it in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

[Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship (Paperback)](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)

Answer (score 0):

You use too many else's. Try to simplify your code, use CASE.